# Generating a download link using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I'm creating an application that lets the user upload an image and then display a direct link in a text field.

Here is the code that is responsible for uploading the image to my bucket and it is triggered when the user's press the upload button.

```
    @IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {

    let imageContained = viewimage.image

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    var storageRef = storage.reference()
    storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "bucket link")

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageContained!, 0.8)! as NSData
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let imageName = dateFormat.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
    let imagePath = "images/\(imageName).jpg"

    let mountainsRef = storageRef.child(imagePath)

    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    mountainsRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: metadata)
```

How would I generate a direct link for the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this below function

```
 func uploadProfilePic(){
        var data = NSData()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ivProfile.image!, 0.8)! as NSData
        // set upload path
        let filePath = "\(userid)" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        self.storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{
                //store downloadURL
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. How can I show the value of downloadURL on a textField I tried [downloadURL = getLink.text!]

Comment: @AhmedAlAbdulaal use this code -> `textField.text = downloadURL`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me [                self.getLink.text = downloadURL
]

Answer (score 1):

Upload function with completion handler.

```
func uploadMedia(completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) { 
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!) {
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                completion((metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!)) 
                // your uploaded photo url.
            }
       }
 }
```

Hope it helps