# Swift - Upload/Retrieve images to/from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want my users to be able to set their profile pictures in my application. I am holding the profile datas which contains the user's profile picture as a table view cell. However, I had problems in my code.

This is my table view function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        let profileInfoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyProfileInfoCell") as! MyProfileInfoCell

        profileInfoCell.profilePicture.tag = indexPath.row

        let user = users[indexPath.row]

        profileInfoCell.username.text = user.username
        profileInfoCell.userEmail.text = user.email
        profileInfoCell.userReputation.text = "has 2 answered likes"

        /*
        let profilePictureStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profilePicture").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
        profilePictureStorageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: {
            data, error in
            if let error = error {

            } else {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                profileInfoCell.profilePicture.image = image!
            }
        })
        */

        return profileInfoCell
    }
```

And this is my imagePickerController function:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyProfileInfoCell!

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
        cell?.profilePicture.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell?.profilePicture.image = image
    }

    /*
    let profilePictureStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://cs401-402.appspot.com").child("profilePicture").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)

    if let profilePicture = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((cell?.profilePicture.image!)!) {
        profilePictureStorageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {
            (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }

            let profilePictureUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

            self.ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("profilePicture").setValue(profilePictureUrl!)
        })
    }
    */

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My program handles setting the profile picture properly. However, when I try to work with Firebase after choosing the profile picture, I am having problems. The commented lines in imagePickerController function causes the multiple creation of my table view cell with profile info.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: [how to upload img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234622/generating-a-download-link-using-firebase/44234926#44234926) & [How to get image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253124/firebase-storage-bucket-issue-ios-swift/44253466#44253466)

Comment: If some answer works for you then upvote it so that it will be helped to other persons, thanks.